# Mongoose not reading from Mongo secondary database

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, database-replication

I've implemented a replica set that I'm using globally. I have my master in Oregon, US and 4 secondaries. California and Virginia, Frankfurt and Sydney. I also have web servers in those same regions as well. Those web servers connect to mongo using mongoose:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var dbUrl = "mongodb://***.***.***.***:27017,***.***.***.***:27017,***.***.***.***:27017,***.***.***.***:27017,***.***.***.***:27017/exampleDb";
var dbOptions : {
   "replSet": {
      "rs_name": "exampleRepSet",
      "readPreference": "ReadPreference.SECONDARY_PREFERRED",
      "read_preference": "ReadPreference.SECONDARY_PREFERRED",
      "w":0,
      "slaveOk": true
    }
}
mongoose.connect(dbUrl, dbOptions);
```

My problem is that my client's have higher latency to the database depending on how far away they are from the master. California get 40ms while Sydney gets 400ms. I don't understand why this is happening since they should be reading off of the secondary database in their region.

I understand that writes must be done to the primary but even if I perform a find then shouldn't it be done on the regional secondary and return pretty quick?

I realize there are some redundant options in that config but I'm getting desperate. I've also tried the option `"ReadPreference.NEAREST"` to no avail.

Comment: What version of mongoose are you running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the following options:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var dbUrl = "mongodb://***.***.***.***:27017,***.***.***.***:27017,***.***.***.***:27017,***.***.***.***:27017,***.***.***.***:27017/exampleDb";

mongoose.connect(dbUrl, {
    server: { 
        readPreference: "nearest", 
        strategy: "ping"
    },
    replset: { 
        rs_name: "exampleRepSet", 
        readPreference: "nearest", 
        strategy: "ping"
    }
});
```

Whilst the documentation specifies `ping` as the default strategy, it seems Mongoose mandates that you specify one when you use `readPreference`.

Also note that `secondaryPreferred` is not the same thing as `nearest`. `secondaryPreferred` prefers reads off of secondary members (as the name suggests) regardless of network latency, where `nearest` prioritizes reads to the member with the lowest amount of network latency.

Short of a misconfiguration in your replica set, make sure your primary is online and reachable - by default Mongoose will refuse to use a secondary if the primary is offline.

Comment: Is it just me or are the mongoose options a bit messy?

Comment: @JoshElias Yes, certainly agree with you there. What makes it worst is a large portion of their documentation is horrible when it comes to describing options and providing examples.

Comment: Yes their documentation is horrible and they are very limited in the examples they provide. One reason I'm moving away from them.

Answer (score 3):

**Edit**

Try setting the read preference on the connection string itself with `mongodb://connection/db/?readPreference=secondary` and not in the dbOptions. I can't find anything in the node-mongodb-native that says a read preference can be added to the replset config. http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/ReplSet.html

**Old Answer**

You may need to set the setting to nearest and not secondary preferred. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/read-preference/#nearest

Comment: I believe the SECONDARY_PREFERRED option will act the same as NEAREST with the exception that it will prefer to read off of a secondary. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/read-preference-mechanics/#replica-set-read-preference-behavior-nearest

Comment: hard coding that option in the mongodb connection url would indeed work but that's not the mongoose solution I was hoping for

Answer (score 0):

```
dbOptions.db = {
   readPreference: "secondaryPreferred",
};
```

This worked for me